# How to remove the first <br> after a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove all the first `<br/>` after an `<h1>` element.

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <br> <!-- <- remove this -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br>
  <br>

  <h1>Test</h1>
  <br> <!-- <- remove this -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

I wrote this piece of code but it does not remove the first br.

```js
$('#myDiv h1').each(function() {        
    $(this).closest("br").remove();
});
```

Comment: So you chose difficult one over the easier one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv h1').each(function(){
    $(this).next('br').remove()
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery [**`next()`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method to do it like following.

```
 $('#myDiv h1').next('br').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as querying `<br/>` tags that come after an `<h1/>` tag inside the `#myDiv` container:

```js
$('#myDiv h1 + br').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <br> <!-- <- remove this -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br>
  <br>

  <h1>Test</h1>
  <br> <!-- <- remove this -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the future reader that wants a vanilla JavaScript solution. Also, I am not sure if the other posters solutions would remove a `<br>` under a different `<h1>` if none were found under one.

```
var eles = document.querySelectorAll('#myDiv h1');
for (var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
  var a = eles[i];
  while (a.nextElementSibling) {
    a = a.nextElementSibling;
    if (a.localName) {
      if(a.localName == 'br') {
        a.parentElement.removeChild(a);
        break;
      }
      else if(a.localName == 'h1')
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I don't know why I used localName.... tagName probably better.

Comment: Why did you choose `localName` instead of `tagName`?

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting `h3` elements, of which your HTML document has none.

Change your selector to target `h1` elements.

```
$('#myDiv h1')
//        ^^
```

EDIT: Looks like you updated the question to target `h1` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) you can write:

```
$('#myDiv h1 + br').remove();
```

```js
console.log('BR : ' + $('#myDiv br').length + '  H1 + BR:' +  $('#myDiv h1 + br').length);
$('#myDiv h1 + br').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myDiv">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <br> <!-- <- remove this -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br>
  <br>

  <h1>Test</h1>
  <br> <!-- <- remove this -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```